# Bernoulli trials required for k successes within a sliding window

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Another question ([Bernoulli trials required for k successes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482918/bernoulli-trials-required-for-k-successes)) asked how many Bernoulli trials with probability $p$ of success are expected before you get $k$ successes, which is given by:
$$\mathbb{E}(X)=\frac{k}{p}$$
How does this answer change if those $k$ successes are required happen within a window of size $n$? To make it concrete, here are some sequences for $k=2, n=3$:

- Success, failure, success $\to$ valid termination state
- Success, failure, failure, success $\to$ need to keep going because the two successes are not within a window of $n=3$ trials
- Success, failure, failure, success, success $\to$ valid termination state because the second and third successes are within a window of $n=3$ trials

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for the probability of getting *k* successes *within* *n* trials, it is best to illustrate through a $5$ set tennis match

eg for your winning a five set tennis match with probability *p* for winning a set, you need to win $3-0, 4-1\;\; or\;\; 5-2$

and the expected # of matches within the window of $5$ will be

$3\cdot\binom20q^0p^2\cdot p + 4\cdot\binom31q^1p^2\cdot p + 5\cdot\binom42q^2p^2\cdot p$

[Note the binomial coefficients and the appended *p's* to take into account that the last set has to be a winning set.]

If it goes beyond the window, you have failed, we can't compute the expectation that you have won within the window !

---

**Answer after explanation of sliding window**

In the first window of three,

- win in $2$ steps with $Pr = p^2$
- win in $3$ steps with $Pr = 2p^2q$

---

- lose, but with last win with $Pr= q^2p$ from where $1/p$ steps needed to win by geometric distribution

---

- lose window  with $Pr = q^3+ 2q^2p\;$ and restart

---

Let E = expected number of games to win, then

$E = 2\cdot p^2 +3\cdot2p^2q +(1/p)(q^2p) + [(q^3+2q^2p)\cdot E]$

Simplify it out

Comment: That makes sense, but it doesn't quite answer the question because it's not easy to convert the probability of success within the window to an (exact) expected # of trials before success. You can use the approximation `E[# of trials] = window size / P(success within window)`, but that doesn't take the sliding window into account, it just assumes that each window is totally independent.

Comment: @Dan: To be precise, what I computed was an exact figure for  E(# of matches played | you won within the window). How can the expectation be computed if you have **failed** (not won within the window) ?

Comment: The window is sliding — you keep doing more trials until you hit a termination state.

Comment: @Dan: What is the sliding window mechanism ? Does one slot open after every turn ? Or does a window of size *n* open after you have failed in the first *n* ? Exact mechanism needs to be told.

Comment: Yes, you keep doing a trial one turn at a time until you hit the termination condition. I added one more example case above where there is a valid termination with 5 trials.